# I need to align a bullet list item with other text on the same line

Tags: css, css-float

I want a bullet with text to appear on the same line as text in a div to its left.  I created an unordered list item in a div to the right of the other div but the bullet and accompanying text appear slightly below the text that is in the div to their left.  How do I get the bullet with text to line up horizontally?  I am pasting my code below.  In addition, I was asked by a responder to post my code at fiddle and to paste the link to that post.  Here is that link:

https://jsfiddle.net/bartonlewis/0v9uh3Lq/2/

Home
    Barton Lewis's Genealogy Pages

- Surnames

```
#colA {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#colB {
    width: 546px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing:.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    }
#colC {
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    }
```

Comment: show your code, edit your question and add your `code`

Comment: okay, thank you.  This is my first post so I'm not sure what to include (both html and css) but I would think both are necessary.

Comment: yes, try to put your code

Comment: try to use fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: how do you put line breaks in your posts here - hitting return seems to post the comment.  thanks i;m new to this (obviously)

Comment: in comment? just edit your post and update it including your code

Comment: include your html code

Answer (score 0):

upon what I understood from you, simply add this to your style sheet

```
ul li { display:inline-block; float:left; }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but that did not work.  I have edited my response and included my code.  perhaps there is something else wrong i am doing there.  if you are able to identify it I would appreciate the further assistance.  thanks, barton

Comment: Would you provide me with your full html and css on jsfiddle so I can help you better

Comment: thank you.  I have not used fiddle before but I signed up and gave the fiddle the name "Barton's 1st fiddle."  I think this makes it public.  Can you see it?  I was getting some error messages after posting the entire html so started with code after the html tag up to the end of the section containing the problem bullet (the header).  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Kindly share with me the url to be able to open it